# The file specified for :r command was not found. sqlcmd in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

i'm writing sqlcmd in SSMS for running bunch of other scripts.this is my script.

```
USE master;
:setvar path "C:\temp\sqlbasics\rollback\"
:setvar currentFile "09 - Create ContactVerificationDetails Table Rollback.sql"
PRINT 'Executing $(path)$(currentFile)';
:r $(path)$(currentFile)
```

while executing i get an error as follows

```
A fatal scripting error occurred.
The file specified for :r command was not found.
```

file saved exactly as mentioned..